# How to build silverlight website & create XAP's using script?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, nant

I am just getting started with Silverlight and have recently added a Silverlight project to an established solution. In this particular scenario my solution included an existing ASP.NET web site which Visual Studio kindly offered to integrated my Silverlight application into, which I accepted.

So everything is fine and all, and the Silverlight XAP is being copied to the web site's ClientBin directory when i was buiding solution through visual studio, But

I want same thing through using nant script when i am used nant script that time all project in the solution are build but recenty added silverlight website do not create XAP's in ClientBin dierctory.

I m using following script :-

target name="build" description="compiles the source code">

exec program="${framework::get-framework-directory(framework::get-target-framework())}
\msbuild.exe" commandline="MY.sln" workingdir="ProjectFolder" />

what are the ways ??

Answer (score 0):

You could reverse-engineer the MsBuild scripts used to build Silverlight apps and .Xap files, the files will be located in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your msbuild compilation should be creating the XAP file in the Bin\Debug folder of the silverlight project.  You can simply use the Nant copy task to move it to the Web project's ClientBin folder.